# System.ExecutionEngineException occuring on fetching contacts in windows phone 8.1 xaml

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am creating an windows phone 8.1 xaml application . In which it takes phone contacts and populated in a list.

I used the following codes to implement this.

```
 var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();

 var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
```

It works good in testing with emulator with less number of contacts. But while testing with real device i breaks after calling FindContactsAsync method.

And i am getting this exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module.

Why this happening? And note that in my phone there are about 1000 contacts.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

To work around this issue, you can disable concurrent garbage collection by modifying the application's configuration file. For more information, see How to: Disable Concurrent Garbage Collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1stbec.aspx